# OpenShift deployment unable to pull image from internal registry: certificate signed by unknown authority

Tags: openshift, openshift-4

I apologize if this seems like a fairly trivial question, but I am not very familiar with OpenShift deployment. I am trying to build a Docker image, push it to an OpenShift internal registry deployed on-premise, and then deploy an app that pulls said image. However, when I run `oc apply -f myapp.yaml`, the created pod fails with an `ImagePullBackOff` error, which is due to an `ErrImagePull` error with the message:

`Failed to pull image "myregistry.openshift.mycompany.com/myproject/myapp:mytag": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = pinging container registry myregistry.openshift.mycompany.com: Get "https://myregistry.openshift.mycompany.com/myproject/v2/": x509: certificate signed by unknown authority`

Contents of `myapp.yaml`:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: myapp
  namespace: myapp
  labels:
    app: myapp
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: myapp
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: myapp
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: myapp
          image: myregistry.openshift.mycompany.com/myproject/myapp:mytag
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
              protocol: TCP
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: path/to/logs
              name: deploymentlogs
            - mountPath: path/to/reports
              name: reports
          securityContext:
            privileged: false
            allowPrivilegeEscalation: false
            capabilities:
              drop:
                - ALL
            runAsNonRoot: true
            seccompProfile:
              type: RuntimeDefault
          resources:
            requests:
              cpu: 100m
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: dockerconfigjson
        # I tried two values for imagePullSecrets, details below.
      volumes:
        - name: deploymentlogs
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: deploymentlogs
        - name: reports
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: reports
```

I tried out two values for `imagePullSecrets` but neither worked, both resulting in the same error.

The previous value of `imagePullSecrets` is `registry-cert` and this is the output of `oc get secret registry-cert -o yaml`:

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  myregistry.openshift.mycompany.com.crt: <long PEM encode in the exported cert>
kind: Secret
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2023-05-22T07:28:52Z"
  name: registry-cert
  namespace: myapp
  resourceVersion: "148422557"
  uid: 17f26b35-c5b4-4280-80d4-d66317f3f9f5
type: Opaque
```

I have already copied this certificate to both `/etc/docker/certs.d/myregistry.openshift.mycompany.com` and `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/`.

The current value of `imagePullSecrets` is `dockerconfigjson` and this is the output of `oc get secret dockerconfigjson -o yaml`:

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  .dockerconfigjson: <long base64 string>
kind: Secret
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2023-05-23T05:39:09Z"
  name: dockerconfigjson
  namespace: myapp
  resourceVersion: "150532046"
  uid: be79c7d1-112e-4c24-905d-669a83505deb
type: kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson
```

Output of `oc get secret dockerconfigjson -o "jsonpath={.data.\.dockerconfigjson}" | base64 --decode` (which is the contents of my `~/.docker/config.json`):

```
{
        "auths": {
                "myregistry.openshift.mycompany.com": {
                        "auth": "base64-encode of '$(oc whoami):$(oc whoami -t)'"
                },
                "https://index.docker.io/v1/": {
                        "auth": "short base64 string"
                }
        }
}
```

Contents of `/etc/docker/daemon.json`:

```
{"insecure-registries": ["myregistry.openshift.mycompany.com"]}
```

---

I doubt that my Docker build/push process is the problem but nevertheless, these are the steps that I go through to build and push my image:

1. Login to OpenShift by running `oc login --token=... --server=...`. To obtain the token, I authenticate as a non-admin user using Azure AD.
2. Login to Docker by running `docker login -u $(oc whoami) -p $(oc whoami -t) myregistry.openshift.mycompany.com`
3. Build the Docker image by running `docker build -f Dockerfile -t myapp:mytag .`
4. Tag the image to the registry by running `docker image tag myapp:mytag myregistry.openshift.mycompany.com/myproject/myapp:mytag`
5. Push the image by running `docker push myregistry.openshift.mycompany.com/myproject/myapp:mytag`